# Google Docs API in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I am trying to use Apps Script with Google Docs API to have a setting within a personally created submenu to change text color, depending on which option is selected in the sub menu. Can someone give me a general idea of how I can get the current color of a specific paragraph and set it to a different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current foreground color of a paragraph use [Method:Paragraph.getAttribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getAttributes()) and  [Method:Paragraph.setAttribute](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#setAttributes(Object)) to set the foreground color.

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.getParagraphs().forEach(par => {
    var style = {};
    if(par.getAttributes().FOREGROUND_COLOR == '#ff0000'){
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#0000ff';
    }else if(par.getAttributes().FOREGROUND_COLOR == '#ff9900'){
      style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#008000';
    }
    par.setAttributes(style);
  })
}
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Here are the list of [Attributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute) you can use.

Comment: I tried using the code you've placed however it makes the whole document that one color.

I'd like it to be an if statement where if paragraph 1 is 'red' it changes to 'blue', then an if statement where if paragraph 2 is 'orange' changes to 'green' for example.

Comment: @AdamSabadash - I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, appreciate it.

Comment: So I used the code you mentioned and it works mostly... however some sections don't change at all and was wondering if that would be a bug within the coding

Comment: Please share a sample doc so I could test it on my end.

Comment: I ended up fixing it be re-identifying the paragraphs as bodies.